# How do i update my DB (database) wowtlk 3.3.5 azerothcore

Tags: azerothcore

I am using the portable Heidisql as the installer version and can't connect to the worldserver/authserver files.

Can I use MySQL community edition/package from the installation guide of Azerothcore? and then use the update tutorial for guidiance?

If not, can somebody make a little video on how to update DB using Heidisql or MySQL? sorry for asking been trying for 3-4 days now understanding the tutorial.

All in all I would really love a video that shows me how to update the DB.
I am using Azerothcore installed with Docker for win 10. Server runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have correctly installed the AzerothCore Database following the official guide:

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Database-Setup

and properly configured your `config.sh` as the above guide explains (you need to do it only once), all you have to do in order to update your database is:

1. update your local sources using `git pull`
2. run the DB assembler `bash apps/db_assembler/db_assembler.sh` and select the option `7`, which will automatically do all the work for you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try take a look at it again and see if i can get it too work. 
Thanks for you're time :-)